# Which camera for turtle3 burger and how to plug it?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I sent these questions to turtlebot@osrfoundation.org , and they answered me to ask them here.

I am preparing a course with Turtlebot3 burgers for Master 2 students at a French engineers school called Efrei.
I intend to make them run on the autonomous race track from that page: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/autonomous_driving/#autonomous-driving

But first, they need to plug the camera on the turtlebot3 burger.
The web page refers to "See Features of 4 screw holes in the page very carefully before mounting on the frame of any conductive materials"
But I could not find that page, even on Google.
Do you know if there is any guide or video for that, please ?

Another question: the webpage refers to that model: https://www.waveshare.com/rpi-camera-g.htm
But the appendix about the raspberry pi camera refers to another one: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/appendix_raspi_cam/
Which one do I have to buy, in order to avoid problems as much as possible ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329102/which-camera-for-turtle3-burger-and-how-to-plug-it-?/) by [Eyrignoux](https://answers.ros.org/users/44171/eyrignoux/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i would recommend you to use the waveshare camere because of the fish eye. and change able lenses.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eyrignoux](https://answers.ros.org/users/44171/eyrignoux/) on 2019-07-26**:
Thank you very much ! Do you have any advice about how to plug it on the turtlebot ?

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-07-26**:
you can use this  item http://www.robotis.us/pi-camera-frame-set/ or may use this 3D print part https://grabcad.com/library/rpi-camera-v2-mount-for-turtlebot-3-1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use a normal USB camera along with a ROS Driver like `cv_camera`. To install it, run this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ros-[YOUR-ROS-DISTRO]-cv-camera
```

Once you have this installed in your TurtleBot3, you can plug it in a USB port and test it running this node:

```
source /opt/ros/[YOUR-ROS-DISTRO]/setup.bash
rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node
```

If it works, then create a launch file for the node and also a static transform publisher from `base_link` to `camera_link`, indicating the approximate distance to where you end up placing your camera. The file would look something like this:

> 

```
<node pkg="cv_camera" type="cv_camera_node" name="cv_camera" output="screen"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_frames_pub" args="0.05 0.0 0.1 0 0 0 /base_link /camera 35"/>
```

If you want a step-by-step walk through of the instructions above, you can check out this video I made:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hH6ov9Ep134&ab_channel=TheConstruct

---

Originally posted by [rodrigo55](https://answers.ros.org/users/53015/rodrigo55/) with karma: 156 on 2021-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2